# C++ rle bmp compression skips last bytes

Tags: c++, bmp

I'm writing a rle compression for bmp files. (it is a part of bigger project) The encode function takes a file containing only pixels (without headers). And everything works well except that it doesn't compress few last bytes  (depending on file size I guess). De compression also works well. 
Thanks in advance for any help!

Here's the code:

```
 #include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef struct SPixel {
    uint8_t red;    
    uint8_t green;
    uint8_t blue;
}PIXEL;

bool compare(SPixel pixel1, SPixel pixel2) {
    if (pixel1.red == pixel2.red && pixel1.green == pixel2.green && pixel1.blue == pixel2.blue)
        return true;
    else return false;
}

void encode(string &input, string &output){
    unsigned short repetition = 1;
    PIXEL current;
    PIXEL next;

    fstream file;
    fstream compressed;
    file.open(input, ios::in | ios::binary);
    if (!file.is_open()) {
        cout << "cannot open file to encode." << endl;
        getchar();
        exit(1);
    }

    compressed.open(output, ios::out | ios::trunc | ios::binary);
    if (!compressed.is_open()) {
        cout << "cannot open file to save encoded file." << endl;
        getchar();
        exit(1);
    }

    file.read((char*)&current, sizeof(PIXEL));
    file.read((char*)&next, sizeof(PIXEL));

    while (!file.eof())
        if (!compare(current, next)) {
            compressed.write((char*)&repetition, sizeof(repetition));
            compressed.write((char*)&current, sizeof(PIXEL));
            repetition = 0;
        }
        repetition++;
        current = next;
        file.read((char*)&next, sizeof(PIXEL));
    }

    file.close();
    compressed.close();
}

void decode(string &input, string &output) {
    fstream file;
    fstream ready;
    PIXEL current;
    unsigned short repetition = 0;

    file.open(input, ios::in | ios::binary);
    if (!file.is_open()) {
        cout << "cannot open file to decode." << endl;
        getchar();
        exit(1);
    }
    ready.open(output, ios::trunc | ios::out | ios::binary);
    if (!ready.is_open()) {
        cout << "cannot open file to save decoded file." << endl;
        getchar();
        exit(1);
    }

    while (!file.eof()){
        file.read((char*)&repetition, sizeof(repetition));
        file.read((char*)&current, sizeof(PIXEL));
        for (int j = 0; j < repetition; j++)
            ready.write((char*)&current, sizeof(PIXEL));
    }

    file.close();
    ready.close();
}
```

Comment: If the last pixel is the same as the next-to-last pixel, when will that be written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `Some programmer dude` has correctly mentioned, you need following corrections.

Insert following code in `encode` function

```
while (!file.eof()) {
    ...
}

if (1 < repetition) {
    compressed.write((char*)&repetition, sizeof(repetition));
    compressed.write((char*)&current, sizeof(PIXEL));
}

file.close();
...
```